# Can the two electromagnetic field tensors be combined into a more general tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

Given the electromagnetic field tensor
$$\begin{align}
F_{\mu\nu}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -E_{x} & -E_{y} & -E_{z}
\\
E_{x} & 0 & B_{z} & -B_{y}
\\
E_{y} & -B_{z} & 0 & B_{x}
\\
E_{z} & B_{y} & -B_{x} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
and its dual
$$\begin{align}
G_{\mu\nu}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B_{x} & B_{y} & B_{z}
\\
-B_{x} & 0 & E_{z} & -E_{y}
\\
-B_{y} & -E_{z} & 0 & E_{x}
\\
-B_{z} & E_{y} & -E_{x} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\,,
\end{align}$$
does there exist a general tensor $H_{\mu\nu}$ that combines $F_{\mu\nu}$ and $G_{\mu\nu}$ into a more general tensor in Minikowski space?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "combining two tensors"?
Which kind of tensor operation do you have in mind?

Comment: Adding the tensors together?

Comment: You can certainly always add tensors. In this case you'll have $H_{\mu\nu}=F_{\mu\nu}+G_{\mu\nu}$ and components of $H$ are just the components of $F$ and $G$ added together.

Comment: I am not sure, but isn't there restrictions on how one can add tensors such that it preserves the lorentz transformation properties of the new tensor?

Comment: Lorentz invariance is always preserved as long as you sum tensors of the same rank (i.e same number of indices).
Therefore it's always ok to sum the $F_{\mu\nu}$ and $G_{\mu\nu}$ of your example, but on the other hand you can not do $A^{\mu}+F^{\mu\nu}+R^{\mu}_{\nu\rho\sigma}$

Comment: You can contract them and get some invariant Lagrange densities, I think.