# What is the physical significance of the fermi-field asymmetric stress-energy tensor?

Tags: fermions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Using the ideas from a previous question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98513/is-there-a-field-equation-which-can-reduce-into-all-three-flavors-of-spin-zero) it can be shown that if one takes the boson spin 1 stress-energy tensor of the form

\begin{align}
T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{spin one}}
=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{8\pi}(E^2+B^2) && S_x/c && S_y/c && S_z/c
\\
S_x/c && -\sigma_{xx} && -\sigma_{xy} && -\sigma_{xz}
\\
S_y/c && -\sigma_{yx} && -\sigma_{yy} && -\sigma_{yz}
\\
S_z/c && -\sigma_{zx} && -\sigma_{zy} && -\sigma_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

created from a boson spin 1 electromagnetic field $F=E+iB$ and changes the spin of $F$ from spin one to spin half, $\{F,A\} \rightarrow \{ \phi_+ , \phi_- \} $ using [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98513/is-there-a-field-equation-which-can-reduce-into-all-three-flavors-of-spin-zero), then $T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{spin one}}$ changes to

\begin{align}
T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{spin half}} 
=
mc^2
\begin{bmatrix}
I && 0 && 0 && i\gamma^{0123}
\\
\gamma^{01} && 0 && 0 && i\gamma^{23}
\\
\gamma^{02} && 0 && 0 && i\gamma^{31}
\\
\gamma^{03} && 0 && 0 && i\gamma^{12}
\end{bmatrix}
,
\end{align}
which I can only understand $T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{spin half}} $ as a fermion spin half stres-energy tensor.

What is the physical significance of $T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{spin half}} $ compared to $T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{spin one}}$?

I am struggling to understand how to interpret $T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{spin half}} $. This fermi-field stress-energy tensor is asymmetric. The divergence of $T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{spin half}} $ is zero.